# Warning in the console output when using the Vuetify v-data-table component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am using the Vuetify *v-data-table* component. Here it is:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-data-table
      :headers="tableHeaders"
      :items="items"
      hide-actions
      class="elevation-1"
    >
      <template slot="items" slot-scope="props">
        <td>{{ props.item.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ props.item.created_at }}</td>
        <td>{{ props.item.updated_at }}</td>
      </template>
    </v-data-table>
    <AddPlanButton/>
  </div>
</template>
```

Here are my headers:

```
data () {
  return {
    items: [],
    tableHeaders: [
      { text: 'Name' },
      { text: 'Created at' },
      { text: 'Updated at' }
    ]
  }
},
```

And I am getting the next warning in the console:

```
[Vuetify] Headers must have a value property that corresponds to a value in the v-model array in "v-data-table"
```

I can translate but I can not understand exactly - what should I do in my code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just as warning message says: headers must have a `value` property (key name in `items` objects list):

```
tableHeaders: [
  { text: 'Name', value: 'name_key_name' },
  { text: 'Created at', value: 'created_key_name' },
  { text: 'Updated at', value: 'updated_key_name' }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a issue, for replicate go in: https://codepen.io/cetor007/pen/mxexWp?editors=1011

the issue happens, in this case. `items[]`-> requered an attribute with name (name) and if name have the same (value) selected all values that have same value.